# SwiftUI Observation Ignores Animations

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a toggle which should trigger an animation of a view appearing. This works as expected when using plain @State within the view ("Is On" text appears with animation):

```
struct ExampleView_State: View {
    @State var isOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $isOn.animation())
            }
            if isOn {
                Section {
                    Text("Is On")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, When this state is moved to an external object (controlled by the new SwiftUI Observation features), this animation is lost:

```
@Observable
class ExampleViewModel_Observation {
    var isOn: Bool = false
}

struct ExampleView_Observation: View {
    @State var viewModel = ExampleViewModel_Observation()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $viewModel.isOn.animation())
            }
            if viewModel.isOn {
                Section {
                    Text("Is On")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The equivalent ObservableObject implementation works as expected:

```
class ExampleViewModel_ObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    var isOn: Bool = false
}

struct ExampleView_ObservableObject: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ExampleViewModel_ObservableObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $viewModel.isOn.animation())
            }
            if viewModel.isOn {
                Section {
                    Text("Is On")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with how I am using @Observable/Swift Observation? Or is this an Apple bug?

Comment: Have you tried adding the animation view modifier?

Comment: This is SwiftUI so why would you want to use an object at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this approach using a `@Bindable`, such as:

```
struct ExampleView_Observation: View {
    @State var viewModel = ExampleViewModel_Observation() 

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var viewModel = viewModel // <-- here
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $viewModel.isOn.animation())
            }
            if viewModel.isOn {
                Section {
                    Text("Is On")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer works for me. Although you have removed the `@State` which will mean the state of the object will be lost on re-render. Keeping the `@State` continues to work too which would be the preferred solution

Comment: certainly, you can keep the `@State` if you need it without loss of functionality. I'll update my answer, since you prefer that option.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Swift don't move it to an class, move it into a struct instead, e.g.

```
struct Example {
    var isOn: Bool = false
    // make sure to have other vars otherwise grouping them in a struct is pointless

    mutating func otherLogic() {}
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @State var example = Example()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $example.isOn.animation())
            }
            if example.isOn {
                Section {
                    Text("Is On")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```